# What is the purpose of the design pattern iClass in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin

I am rewriting a Xamarin project in Native iOS (Objective-C)

I noticed that each class has its corresponding iClass interface.

What is the purpose of this design pattern? Is this the norm for Xamarin development or just a style? I know the purpose of interfaces and they're like protocols in Objective-C but I don't see the purpose of writing a protocol for each class that you only used once?

Will it cause errors if I just rewrite both the class and the iClass as a single class in Objective-C? I also noticed how they pass these iClass in parameters instead of just conforming to it?

Example Code

```
public interface ICar {


}



public class Car: ICar {

}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a basic way of achieving inversion of control. This allows dependencies between types to be abstracted, so that all parts of the program are unit testable.

On the other hand, it violates one of the other SOLID principles, the interface segregation principle (ideally, these should be abstract base classes, not interfaces).

If you merge all the interfaces into the classes, you'll lose the unit-testability of the code base.